# clone append to included page

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui

Can a clone be appended to a page that is only included in another page?
For example, we have home.php: in home.php, anotherpage.php is included in one of its divs.
Can I clone an image from home.php to one of the divs of the included page anotherpage.php? [I'm asking because I didn't find any straight forward answer over the net..]

Comment: How do you *include* anotherpage.html into home.html, do you use frameset ? ajax ? other ? What do you mean by cloning an image, have a new image or display the same image twice ?

Comment: @sinsedrix my friend did it like this using a php script <div id="container"><?php include 'home.php'; ?></div>
by clone, i mean like cloning in jquery.. $('#img').clone().appendTo('#someDivInHomeDotPhp');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The PHP is processed by the server first and then delivered to the user. Then the JavaScript is processed by the user. So the server creates a page (home.html) with all the content assembled together, and the resulting page can apply jQuery to any part of it. BTW, is your server setup to parse .html pages as PHP?

Comment: They are actually PHP. My files here are .php and not .html, I thought it didn't matter 'cause I was asking a question about jquery and html but didn't realize til after I was asked how I "included" the page (used php script). And thank you sir for answering.